# micropython sleep_us lies?

Tags: python, time, micropython

working on another project I faced something weird in working with time.
especially with `time.ticks_us()`

using ESP32 S2 module
code:

```
from time import ticks_us, sleep_us
for i in range(100):
    t2 = ticks_us()
    sleep_us(1)
    t = ticks_us() - t2
    print(t)
```

not getting close to 1us.

min 105 us

max 120 us

I remember that its python (micropython in my case) but still.
its also depends on the running frequency

am i wrong?

is this "mode" is useless? useconds

Comment: "not getting close to 50us".  Did you mean 100us?  Your code and comment don't agree.    Most sleeps (unless they are spin-waits or a real-time OS) wait a *minimum* of the given time.

Comment: right. updated. put wrong values. 1us giveds 100-120

Comment: The docs for this say "This function attempts to provide an accurate delay of at least us microseconds, but it may take longer if the system has other higher priority processing to perform." Is there any higher priority processing happening?

Comment: that much of the offset?! so it's useless ?! for example: stepper driver with microsteps mode cannot be accurate at all. also this is the only task running.

Comment: il try to use direct register manipulation for this. will see if itll help. but this is still an issue i thik

Comment: There's a reason people use dedicated controllers for stepper drivers. This is a problem that's typically solved with special-purpose hardware.

Comment: know that. BUT! micropython works with stepper motors. but you cant use microstep mode. at least high number. 8+. i didnt want to write the program in cpp. not needed this time. doesnt have to be accurate. but i faced that the sleep function working not as i expected.

Comment: Depending on how it's implemented on your specific microcontroller, which you forgot to name, `print` might be taking up the majority of the time here.  You might try storing that data in an array and printing it after the loop.  However, accurate control of stepper motors is something I wouldn't attempt to do in Python.

Comment: This is nothing to do with print. Since its happening after the calculation.

Comment: It looks like you have also asked this and got some responses on [MicroPython GitHub discussions](https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions/13421)? There are many other posts on similar topics if you just search there for 'stepper' - and if you're still stuck you'll probably get better answers by asking there instead of here. It's probably possible to do what you want but I think you'll need to use interrupts and/or some kind of hardware timing to get there.

Comment: I did asked there too, but there is not enough ppl to get an answer. Im sure stakc community is much bigger and someone has the answer.  Interrupts has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with micropython, but on a typical multithreaded OS a sleep gives up the current thread's time slice.  The sleep is a *minimum* time, but the process' thread may not get scheduled again for a while.  A spin-wait (loop without giving up the thread's timeslice) uses more CPU but can be much more accurate.  They are useful for very short waits.

A Windows OS example:

```
import time

def spinwait(t):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while time.perf_counter() - start < t:
        pass

# Using sleep
trials = []
for _ in range(1000):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    time.sleep(1e-6)
    trials.append(time.perf_counter() - start)
print(f'min={min(trials):.09f}, ave={sum(trials) / 1000:.09f}, max={max(trials):.09f}')

# using spinwait
trials = []
for _ in range(1000):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    spinwait(1e-6)
    trials.append(time.perf_counter() - start)
print(f'min={min(trials):.09f}, ave={sum(trials) / 1000:.09f}, max={max(trials):.09f}')
```

Output:

```
min=0.000006700, ave=0.000007603, max=0.000527600
min=0.000001500, ave=0.000001682, max=0.000003900
```

Comment: this is different in a lot of ways. mP runs on simple cores with very limited resources. no other tasks running unless you run them in purpose. i'm running it on 240mhz mcu running only one thread on one core.

Comment: @aleXela I'm just saying if the sleep isn't accurate, something else is probably going on and a spinwait may be more appropriate.  Are you sure there are no other interrupts in the system?

Comment: i'm sure 100% you are right about "something". but what is the purpose of such function then? with such a big error?

Comment: @aleXela Sleep is generally useful only if the wait time is an order of magnitude greater than the thread time slice.  If you are getting 100-200us that's probably the time slice rate of your processor.  A 1-second sleep wouldn't be affected by 1.001-1.002 accuracy.

Comment: again, right ) and this function still there. laying useless )

Answer (score -1):

**Just a guess since it's embedded development**

The MCU is working in ticks and has it's machine cycle which handle instructions (and there might be interrupts or other system function which has higher priority). If the MCU is slow enough it might not notice the sleep_us() was already working for 100us and it ends the function after some time above 100us.

I would suggest if something really need to happens that often then just let it be in some while() loop. Or if it's something that might be interrupt handled then let's use it. You might also want to use a state machine (or token handling) if the process has an exact action order.

Comment: you right about the ticks. but this function takes it into accounts. depends on the freq you set. while loop will not do the job i need. working with stepper motor. most of the time is spent on setting hardware (pin to HIGH and Low)